# How to print a dict with some deviations added to its values?

Tags: python, dictionary, random

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how can I append my dictionary values so that every time I print them, they will be slightly different e.i ±10% deviation.

Example code:

```
shop = {
 'Milk': 1.24,
 'Coffee': 8.68,
 'Bread': 1.99,
 'Apples': 0.96,
 'Cakes': 12.96,

}
```

Something to make the shop.values change ±10%:

```
 random_keys = random.choices(population=list(stock.keys()), k=random.randrange(2, 5))
 print({k: stock[k] for k in random_keys})
```

End result:

```
{'Milk': 1.35, 'Cakes' : 12.82}
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly ?

Comment: So for example make the value random every time but only within a specified range ie ±10%. I tried using append and for functions but I always get different errors or the code doesn't seem to make too much sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

for key in shop:

   print ( key, '%.2f' %(shop[key]*random.uniform(0.9,1.1)))
```

if u need a percentage deviation of 10% --> you have to multiply between 0.9 and 1.1

Answer (score 1):

Each time you want to print your dictionary with new random values, you could call this function:

```
import random
from typing import Dict    


def print_with_deviations(my_dict: Dict[str, float],
                          *,
                          deviation: float = 0.1) -> None:
    print({key: f'{value * random.uniform(1 - deviation, 1 + deviation):.2f}' 
           for key, value in my_dict.items()})
```

Just like this: `print_with_deviations(shop)`
Or if you want to use not 10% but another deviation:

```
print_with_deviations(shop, deviation=0.2)
```